# Can I use the zlib header as a delimiter?

Tags: zlib

I have multiple blocks of data compressed with zlib. I want to concatenate these blocks of data and store that in one file.

Obviously, I could use something like JSON or XML to separate the zlib data blocks, but I'm wondering if, to save space, I can just search for the next `78 01`, `78 9C` or `78 DA`?

Basically my question is, can, theoretically, these byte combinations exist in a zlib data stream, or can I be sure that when I find one of these byte combinations, a new zlib data block is started, and the end is at the found position minus one?

I know the uncompressed data blocks are always 1024 bytes or less in length, so the compressed stream will never be > 1024 bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't.  Any byte sequence can appear in the compressed data.  At any byte position, there is a probability of 1/1024 of finding a valid zlib header.  So you will find a *lot* of valid zlib headers in a long compressed stream that are not actually zlib headers.

You could create your own byte stuffing scheme that wraps around arbitrary data, including zlib streams or anything else, that assures that certain sequences cannot occur unless they really are delimiters.  Such schemes can incur an arbitrarily small expansion of the data.  For example if you find three `0xff`'s in a row in the data, then insert a `0x00` byte.  Then `0xff 0xff 0xff 0xff` can be a delimiter, since it will never appear in the data.  This will only expand the stream, on average, by about 0.000006%.